# DB2 SQL CROSSTAB

Tags: sql, db2, crosstab

I would like to output a table, transformed to a crosstab with a Select statement. How could I do this with DB2 SQL?

```
ROW       | Columns  | VALUES             _________________________________
_____________________________     -->            Column1 | Column2  | Column3   
1         | 1        | 12                 _________________________________
1         | 2        | 25                 Row 1|     12  |     25  |     11
1         | 3        | 11                 Row 2|     30  |      5  |     15
2         | 1        | 30
2         | 2        | 5
2         | 3        | 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the values (and you seem to), then conditional aggregation is a simple method for implementing this:

```
select row,
       max(case when column = 1 then value end) as column1,
       max(case when column = 2 then value end) as column2,
       max(case when column = 3 then value end) as column2
from t
group by row;
```